# How do I convert Date String containing "ET" into Python Date/Time?

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch dates from articles that are given in format like `Jan. 23, 2005 11:14 pm ET`. What should I pass in `strftime` to fetch the DateTime from this format? I only need the day, month, and year part only.

Answer (score 1):

Using [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('Jan. 23, 2005 11:14 pm ET', '%b. %d, %Y %I:%M %p ET')
print(date)
```

You can then access the year, month and day using `date.year`, `date.month`, `date.day`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fetch day, month, and year from a given string you can use the following code

```
x = "Jan. 23, 2005 11:14 pm ET"
x = x.split(" ")
date = x[1][:-1]
year = x[2]
month = x[0][:-1]
print("date:", date)
print("month:", month)
print("year:", year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split string on the 3rd whitespace and parse with `.strptime`. You need to make a datetime first since `datetime.date` doesn't have a `.strptime` function:

```
import datetime

s = "Jan. 23, 2005 11:14 pm ET"
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(" ".join(s.split(" ")[:3]), "%b. %d, %Y").date()
print(dt)
```

With non-standard libraries:

```
import dateutil.parser
import pytz
dt = dateutil.parser.parse(s, tzinfos={"ET": pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")})
print(dt)
```